# How to show previous / next day by clicking right and left arrows using Date Picker

Tags: swift, xcode

Here is what I have so far.

Now, I am able to show the date chosen through the Date Picker in InputTextField.

I would like to add left and right arrows next to the InputTextField so that I can show the previous/next day by clicking those arrows.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var InputTextField: UITextField!

  private var datePicker: UIDatePicker?


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker?.datePickerMode = .date
    datePicker?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.dateChanged(datePicker:)), for: .valueChanged)

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.viewTapped(gestureRecognizer:)))

    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    InputTextField.inputView = datePicker


}


@objc func viewTapped (gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}


@objc func dateChanged (datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"

    InputTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to

1. add two subview to your UI, which are left arrow and right arrow.
2. add target-action/gesture to these two subviews.
3. in action triggered function, update `datePicker` and `InputTextField`

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Could you explain more about how I can update datePicker ?